# Form validation. Optimize Angular ng-required expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm creating a form validation and it becomes too ugly and heavy because of too many fields that need to be validated. I need to optimize it. So, I'm making required any field based on the other fields values using ng-required. When the user insert a value in one of the fields then the rest of them loose the required quality and the form becomes valid. So, for that I created an expression like this:

```
<input ng-model="field.one" ng-required="
!field.two && 
!field.three && 
!field.four && 
!field.five && 
!field.six && 
... && 
!filed.twenty"/>

<input ng-model="field.two" ng-required="
!field.one && 
!field.three && 
!field.four && 
!field.five && 
!field.six && 
... && 
!filed.twenty"/>
```

So, I intend to move the required expression in the controller or where you think it should be moved in order to optimize and organize the code. I was thinking to encapsulate it in a function inside of controller but I didn't succeed. I tried something like this:

```
VIEW
<input ng-model="field.one" ng-required="myFunc(field.one)"/>

CTRL
$scope.myFunc = function(modelField){
    anything I tried in this fn I didn't make it to work syncronized with
    the field models, updating their models based on user interaction :)      
}
```

Please, is there someone that has an ideea how should be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer one scope variable which is bound to all input field's ng-required attribute. And on change of any of the input field toggle this variable.

http://plnkr.co/edit/PVXVD9RKM8cMwCVjFA7c?p=preview

```
<input type="text" ng-change="onChange(userName1, 'name1')" name="name1" ng-model="userName1" ng-required="required">
<input type="text" ng-change="onChange(userName2, 'name2')" name="name2" ng-model="userName2" ng-required="required">

   $scope.required = true;
   $scope.userNames = [];
   $scope.onChange = function(val, name) {
     if (val) {
       if ($scope.userNames.indexOf(name) == -1) {
         $scope.userNames.push(name);
       }
       $scope.required = false;
     } else {
       if ($scope.userNames.indexOf(name) !== -1) {
         $scope.userNames.splice($scope.userNames.indexOf(name), 1);
       }
       if ($scope.userNames.length === 0) {
         $scope.required = true;
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Thank's man, nice to have you on the forum and smart solution btw!

Comment: Is there a way to move this functionality in a directive to keep clean the controller?or this kind of mehtods should stay on the controller? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible and that was  my initial thought too. ( I thought it would be better to avoid the ng-change on each input). Check this plunker for my-required directive. http://plnkr.co/edit/khnLGtarAlcQiLzBZiOP?p=preview . As long as the new directive does not create new scope the same variable can be shared.

Comment: Thanks, it's working perfect. Regarding, checkboxes and selects 'on' should be replaced with 'onchance' event?

Comment: So, probably one solution is to check the type of $element and then apply the event type

Comment: yes you could use on('change') for other types such as checkbox. Make sure to change val variable too. For instance val variable should be $element[0].checked.

Comment: Thanks. It is correct or natural to access the required variable, in case of checkboxes, like $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.required in order to update the value?i m using a module to generate the checkboxes based o a webservice response and the checkboxes scopes are dipper than the other fields. This was the only way that i found to accsess the required variable.

Comment: Accessing using $parent is something I would suggest avoiding as it is very brittle code. Once you change DOM or bring in one more scope you will have to modify this code. Try using broadcast/emit mechanism. Once the checkbox value is changed you can broadcast and update the value of the necessary fields in parent hierarchy.  You can find many articles/docs related to this event mechanism.